# How to use global_step to calculate the predicate for a call to tf.cond?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to execute different computations based on the value of `global step`. Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
incr_global_step = global_step.assign(global_step + 1)

w = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.mod(global_step, 2), 0),
            lambda : tf.get_variable('w1', initializer=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int32)),
            lambda : tf.get_variable('w2', initializer=tf.ones([], dtype=tf.int32)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run([w, incr_global_step]))
```

I am getting the following error:

```py
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value global_step
 [[Node: global_step/read = Identity[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@global_step"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](global_step)]]
```

Is this expected behaviour? If so, what am I doing wrong?

I am using tensorflow 1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yeah this is pretty strange indeed. I was able to run your code with the following modifications:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
incr_global_step = global_step.assign(global_step + 1)

w = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.mod(global_step.initialized_value(), 2), 0),
            lambda : tf.get_variable('w1', initializer=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int32)),
            lambda : tf.get_variable('w2', initializer=tf.ones([], dtype=tf.int32)).initialized_value())

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run([w, incr_global_step]))
```

Note that I had to add [`initialized_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#initialized_value) to `global_step` and the variable `'w2'` in `tf.cond`, but somehow *not* to `'w1'` (you can put it too and it will work, but it will not file if you don't, apparently). This method, as the documentation mentions, is not generally needed, and it just gives a "view" of the variable that is guaranteed to be used *after* it has been initialized. Why `tf.cond` requires you to use it, and why in such inconsistent manner, I don't know.

Besides that, note that the way you are running your code is actually not deterministic. In general you would get this:

```
[1, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 3]
[0, 4]
```

But not always. Here is an output I just got:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 3]
[0, 4]
```

This is because the order in which the increment and the conditional are run is not deterministic. It is better to be explicit about the dependencies, so if you want `w` to run *after* the increment, you would do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
incr_global_step = global_step.assign(global_step + 1)

with tf.control_dependencies([incr_global_step]):
    w = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.mod(global_step.initialized_value(), 2), 0),
                lambda : tf.get_variable('w1', initializer=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int32)).initialized_value(),
                lambda : tf.get_variable('w2', initializer=tf.ones([], dtype=tf.int32)).initialized_value())

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run([w, incr_global_step]))
```

Which amazingly requires me to add `initialized_value` for `'w1'` too. This is really inconsistent. Also, the output in this case is:

```
[0, 2]
[1, 3]
[0, 4]
[1, 5]
```

Now, it annoys me that the result of the increment starts at two. It looks like the increment was run once more than expected. So I feel `tf.cond` somehow enforces one extra first run, which would be the cause for its weird behavior.

If you want the opposite, have `w` run *before* the increment, you could do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.mod(global_step.initialized_value(), 2), 0),
            lambda : tf.get_variable('w1', initializer=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int32)),
            lambda : tf.get_variable('w2', initializer=tf.ones([], dtype=tf.int32)).initialized_value())

with tf.control_dependencies([w]):
    incr_global_step = global_step.assign(global_step + 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run([w, incr_global_step]))
```

Yes, I don't need `'w1'`'s `initialized_value` anymore again. This produces:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[0, 3]
[1, 4]
```

Here the increments, I think, make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I seems to me that global_step is added to the global variables collection by default. For my example `print(tf.global_variables())` yields `[<tf.Variable 'global_step:0' shape=() dtype=int64_ref>, <tf.Variable 'w1:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'w2:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>]`

Comment: @GeertH Woops you're truly right, I tried it in my machine but looked in the wrong place, so I thought `tf.train.get_or_create_global_step` was not adding the newly created global step to the global variables collection (which I found weird but whatever). I'll take a second look.

Comment: @GeertH I've changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works in tensorflow 1.2. However, in tensorflow 1.3 both my initial code and your solution raise a ValueError. The error message says that you are required to use lambda initializers for variables inside conditional branches. Indeed, when I create the variables like this `tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)` and `tf.get_variable('w2', shape=[], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.ones_initializer)` the error is gone and you can leave out the `initialized_value()` calls.

Comment: @GeertH That's interesting, thanks for that feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `placeholder_with_default`.

```
global_step = tf.placeholder_with_default(1, shape=[], name='global_step')
```